# Proof of the definition of Frobenius norm

Tags: normed-spaces, trace, frobenius-method

We already know from the definition of Frobenius norm that : \begin{equation}
\boxed{\mathit{||A||}_{F}=\sqrt{\mathop{\mathrm{trace}}(A^*A)}.}
\end{equation}
But how can we prove it since the trace of a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is defined to be the sum of its diagonal elements such that :
$ \mathop{\mathrm{trace}}(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathit{X}_{ii}$.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: How to prove the definition of Frobenius norm, why is it defined to be the trace of A*A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ (complex) matrix, the Frobenius norm is originally defined as:
\begin{align}
\left\Vert A\right\Vert_F^2
=\sum_{i,j}\vert a_{ij}\vert^2
=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^\ast a_{ij}.
\end{align}
On the other hand, observe that $A^\ast A$ is of size $n\times n$, and we can write the diagonal entries of $A^\ast A$ explicitly:
\begin{align}
A^\ast A=\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i}a_{i1}^\ast a_{i1}&*&\cdots&*\\
*&\sum_{i}a_{i2}^\ast a_{i2}&\cdots&*\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
*&*&\cdots&\sum_{i}a_{in}^\ast a_{in}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
This reveals that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{trace}(A^\ast A)
=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i}a_{ij}^\ast a_{ij}
=\left\Vert A\right\Vert_F^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when showing explicitly the diagonal entries it becomes clear that it's the same as the original definition!